# Wordpress integrated into existing site - use php includes for existing site footer and header

Tags: php, wordpress, include

I have an existing site using html/css/php. I've integrated a WordPress blog to the site and would like to use my existing site's footer and header includes.

> www.existingsite.com/blog

My folder structure is set up with my WordPress blog in a separate folder.

```
existingsite_root -> blog -> index.php

existingsite_root -> inc --> footer.inc
```

In my blog's index, how do I go up a layer in code to call my existing site's footer?

I've tried this:

```
<?php require( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '../inc/footer.inc.php'); ?>
```

However, since this is a string `../` is appended as text instead of instructing to go up and grab the footer file from my inc folder.

Comment: It may be easier to just copy the code of your current sites header and footer into the header.php and footer.php files that are in your theme folder

Comment: I'd be taking it from the approach of duplicating/editing the theme, or creating a plugin that hooks into the wordpress header and footer.

Comment: The existing site's header or footer may be updated by someone other than myself. I dont want to risk the chance of the blog's versions being missed.